# How to use Saxon/C to execute an XQuery from PHP?

Tags: php, windows, xquery, saxon

The [Saxon/C documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) begins by saying;

> Saxon/C is currently on beta release: offering the Saxon-HE product for the C/C++ programming platform. APIs are offered currently to run XSLT 2.0 and **XQuery** 1.0 from C/C++ or **PHP** applications.

which implies that Saxon/C can be used to execute an XQuery from PHP, but can it? There is Saxon/C documentation about XSLT, but not XQuery.

Can Saxon/C be used to run an XQuery from PHP and if so, is there any documentation?

**Edit**: I'm running the Windows version of Saxon/C.

Comment: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/classSaxonProcessor.html suggests the C++ API has both a method to create a `newTransformer` as well as a `newXQueryProcessor`. Whether both features are as well exposed to PHP I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP API documentation on Saxon/C has what you need:

http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/php_api.xml

Also check out the examples in the samples directory in the download zip file. See the file xqueryExamples.php

Comment: Thanks. I tried `$xproc = $proc->XQueryProcessor();` but it returns a fatal error `Call to undefined method SaxonProcessor::XQueryProcessor()`. The latest Windows download (beta v0.3.1) is missing the file `xqueryExamples.php`.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I'm running the Windows version of Saxon/C.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing whats in the C++ API to what is in the PHP API. Please see the example file: https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.6/hec/samples/xqueryExamples.php

Comment: Thanks again. However that sample throws an error too: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SaxonProcessor::importXQueryFile()`;

Comment: My apologies I have given you the samples for the new Saxon/C API. I have replaced the files in the folder. Please download it again.

Comment: Great. It's working now. Thank you for your help. Btw on page [http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/php_api.xml](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/php_api.xml) I think line `void setQueryFile($string $filename)` should be `string` not `$string`.